# Merging Firebase Data into Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

To start off I have 2 sets of data stored in Firebase. I will include both sets in a photo.

[image: Photo of All users]

This first photo shows where I keep all the user's profiles.

When someone checks in on the app I store their username and check-in time at a different place. 
[image: Photo of checked in users]

In the photo above you will be able to see that there are currently 2 users checked in on "12-3-2017 Block 2"

I have no problem storing the data.

I do however have problems displaying the data.

I want to be able to create a UITableView that shows all the users who are checked in and the time they checked in while in the same list show all the users who have yet to checkin.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

 struct checkInStruct {

let userName : String!
let hour : String!
let minutes : String!
let userNameFromAllUsers : String!

 }


class checkInDaysTableViewController: UITableViewController {


//Variables
var lastChildNameSegue = ""


var posts = [checkInStruct]()
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = "\(lastChildNameSegue)"


    print("Name of Child After Segue -> \(lastChildNameSegue)")


    loadCheckedInUsers()
    loadAllUsers()

    print(posts)


}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

    let userName = posts[indexPath.row].userName
    let hour = posts[indexPath.row].hour
    var minute = posts[indexPath.row].minutes
    let userNameOfAllUsers = posts[indexPath.row].userNameFromAllUsers

    let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel


    if(hour == nil || hour == ""){
        //Users isnt signed in
        label1.text = "\(userName!)"
        label2.text = "User Not checked in"
    }else{
        label1.text = "\(userName!)"
        label2.text = "\(hour!):\(minute!)"
    }


    return cell!
}

func loadCheckedInUsers (){

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let userID = user?.uid

    databaseRef.child("users").child("\(userID!)").child("checkins").child("\(lastChildNameSegue)").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


        let userNameSnapValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let userName = userNameSnapValue?["userName"] as? String


        let hourSnapValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let hour = hourSnapValue?["hour"] as? String

        let minutesValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let minutes = minutesValue?["minutes"] as? String

        print(userName!)
        print(hour!)
        print(minutes!)

        self.posts.insert(checkInStruct(userName: userName, hour: hour, minutes: minutes, userNameFromAllUsers: userName) , at: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()


    })
}

func loadAllUsers(){

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let userID = user?.uid

    databaseRef.child("users").child("\(userID!)").child("employeesorstudents").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


        let userNameSnapValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let userName = userNameSnapValue?["userName"] as? String

        let hour = ""
        let minutes = ""

        print(userName!)

        self.posts.insert(checkInStruct(userName: userName, hour: hour, minutes: minutes, userNameFromAllUsers: userName) , at: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })
}



}
```

As you can see I am storing data in one struct.

However, on the app, it is showing both the name of the user from the database of all users and the checked in users.

[image: Screenshot]

In the screenshot, you will see "Brandon Happy" has a check-in time and then he reappears again saying he was never checked in. How can I delete the duplicate data from the struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good however what you should do is not add data to the struct if it already exists so what you need to do is fix your loadAllUsers() function.

```
func loadAllUsers(){

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let userID = user?.uid

    databaseRef.child("users").child("\(userID!)").child("employeesorstudents").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


        let userNameSnapValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let userName = userNameSnapValue?["userName"] as? String

        let hour = ""
        let minutes = ""

        print(userName!)

        databaseRef.child("users").child("\(userID!)").child("checkins").child("\(self.lastChildNameSegue)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.hasChild("\(userName!)"){
                print("User already checked in")
            }else{
                print("user has not yet checked in")
                self.posts.insert(checkInStruct(userName: userName, hour: hour, minutes: minutes, userNameFromAllUsers: userName) , at: 0)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        })




    })
}
```

In the if statement it will figure out if the user has or has not been checked in yet and then adds it to the struct if they have not been checked in.